# Last version of pgfplots, error with LuaLaTeX

Tags: pgfplots, luatex

I have just installed the last version of `pgfplots` (version **1.10**) in my local `texmf` directory but when I try to compile a file with `LuaLaTeX` I get the following error:

```
(/home/red/texmf/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code.tex
! LuaTeX error <\directlua >:1: module 'pgfplots' not found:
    no field package.preload['pgfplots']
    [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'pgfplots'
    [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'pgfplots'
    [oberdiek.luatex.kpse_module_loader] Search failed
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    <\directlua >:1: in main chunk.
<argument> ...e(\pgfplotsDQ pgfplots\pgfplotsDQ )}

l.1993 }
        %
?
```

If I press enter the compilation finishes without other errors and the file look fine but what is this error?

If I instead use the `texlive` version of `pgfplots` (**1.2.2**) then no errors at all (but I need the last version not the older one...)

Comment: With a recently updated TeX Live 2013, having `pgfplots` 1.10 and PGF 3.0 things seem to work fine. Which version of `pgf` do you have? The following works for me, if it does for you as well, can you create a minimal example demonstrating the problem? `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. `Package: pgf 2013/12/18 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.14)`, also this is installed in my local `texmf` dir. Your example gives me the same error

Comment: @TorbjørnT. what version of `LuaTeX` do you have? Mine is `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.1-2011120612`

Comment: That could perhaps be the cause, I have `LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013070317  (TeX Live 2013) (rev 4627)`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I solved the problem adding the `ppa` for `TexLive 2012`, this changes the version of LuaTeX to the 0.70. **2** ... I don't know if the problem was `LuaTeX` or something different

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved by upgrading LuaTeX to a newer version.